# Berry connection in a solid

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, berry-pancharatnam-phase

I am having troubles to understand an equation-sign for the Berry connection in a solid.

The general formula reads

\begin{equation}
\vec{A}(\vec{R}) = \mathrm{i} \langle \Psi(\vec{R}) \, | \nabla_{\vec{R}} \, | \, \Psi(\vec{R}) \rangle \text{.}
\end{equation}

Now assuming that 
\begin{equation}
H_0 \psi_{\vec{k}}^n (\vec{r}) = E_n(\vec{k}) \psi_{\vec{k}}^n (\vec{r}) \text{,}
\end{equation}

where $u_{\vec{k}}^n$ denotes the function coming from the Bloch-wavefunctions $\psi_{\vec{k}}^n (\vec{r}) = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}} u_{\vec{k}}^n(\vec{r})$, it seems (for $\vec{R} \equiv \vec{k}$) to be too obvious to explain why ...

\begin{equation}
\vec{A^n}(\vec{k}) = \mathrm{i} \cdot \left( \mathrm{i} \cdot \langle u_{\vec{k}}^n \, | \vec{r} \, | \, u_{\vec{k}}^n \rangle + \langle u_{\vec{k}}^n \, | \nabla_{\vec{k}} \, | \, u_{\vec{k}}^n \rangle \right) = \mathrm{i} \cdot \langle u_{\vec{k}}^n \, | \nabla_{\vec{k}} \, | \, u_{\vec{k}}^n \rangle
\end{equation}

... the first term vanishes.

I would be grateful if someone could help me out.

Comment: How does your final equation follow from your first equation?

Comment: You identify $\langle \vec{r} \, | \, \Psi(\vec{R}) \rangle \equiv \psi_{\vec{k}}^n(\vec{r})$.  Then the plane-wave-factors cancel out.

Comment: Do you have a reference? Is it possible that the choice $|\Psi(\mathbf{R})\rangle = |u_n(\mathbf{k})\rangle$ is being made?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also considered this identification. :-) My first reference is this arxiv article. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.02295.pdf; Eq. (2.20) is the definition of the Berry connection as above.
Looking at eqs (2.39) and (2.40) supports your choice of identification.
However... What is bothering me with this interpretation is that the function $| u_n(\vec{k}) \rangle$ is not a physical state in a Hilbert space, is it? Only the full Bloch-wavefunction (with plane-wave-factor) should be a physical state. (?)

Comment: I don't see why the latter statement should be true. $\exp\left(-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}\right)$ is a unitary operator. Applying it to a physical state should give back a physical state.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbf{k}$ is not a parameter of the Hamiltonian $H_0$ for the eigensystem  of your second equation. For the general definition of Berry connection, the Hamiltonian $H(\mathbf{R})$ depends on the parameter $\mathbf{R}$. So for Bloch states, one should use $u_{n\mathbf{k}}$ for the eigensystem $H_{\mathbf{k}}u_{n\mathbf{k}}=E_{n\mathbf{k}}u_{n\mathbf{k}}$, where $H_{\mathbf{k}} = e^{-i \mathbf{k \cdot r}}He^{i \mathbf{k \cdot r}}$.